# Trying to add a required attribute to a select box when checkbox is ticked - JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, attributes, box, parsley

I'm having a little trouble adding a 'required' attribute to a select box when a checkbox is checked.

Here's my code so far.

```
$('.turn_on').change(function(){
    $('.form_field select').attr('required');
});
```

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prop(propertyName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) set the property

```
$('.turn_on').change(function(){
    //set required to true/false based on checked box checked state
    $('.form_field select').prop('required', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Have tried that but it's still not working. Have added a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/rc59xus2/

Comment: @FrazerFindlater https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/whkysuf8/ you added code in wrong box

Comment: That's embarrassing! Thanks for that. I see it's working in the fiddle, however, it's not working in my environment. I think it might have something to do with me using parsley.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the attribute but get the attribute. So, use like this:

```
$('.form_field select').attr('required',true);
```